# how to redirect everything to SSL https except a few urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In my htaccess i use the following rule to redirect everything under SSL,
now i need to add a few exception, for example 
http://www.mysite/blog-feed.html must be reachable for the http protocol.

```
#ALWAYS REDIRECT TO SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can just try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog-feed.html
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```